# No visible @interface for class

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

My `Car.m` implementation file is as follows. Here I have 1 private method **engineStarting**.

Here I have used class extension concept to introduce
private method  and I have also used `Car+Maintainance` as a category.

```
 #import "Car.h"

//private methods

@interface Car()
-(BOOL) engineStarting;
@end


@implementation Car

@synthesize model=_model;

-(void)drive{
    NSLog(@"%@ is driving",_model);
}
-(void)stop{
    NSLog(@"%@ has stopped now",_model);
}
-(void)turnleft{
    NSLog(@"%@ is turning left",_model);
}
-(void)turnright{
    NSLog(@"%@ is turning right",_model);
}
-(BOOL) engineStarting{
    return true;
}
```

My **main.m** file looks like

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Car.h"
#import "Car+Maintanance.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
        Car *car=[[Car alloc]init];
        car.model=@"maruti";

        //using car its own methods
        // i am getting error in this line(no visible @interface......)
        [car engineStarting];  
        [car drive];
        [car stop];
        [car turnleft];
        [car turnright];

        //using maintainanace
        if([car neddOilChange]){
            [car changeOil];
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what's your goal? `engineStarting` is defined within a class extension, hence not visible from external. You need to declare it in `Car.h`.

Comment: if i declare it in care.h and it will be public . I want it to be Private

Comment: What are trying to do? What's your goal? I think you should read about OOP.

Comment: @shruthibr, you cannot access to a _private_ method from outside of the class; so if you want to call `[car engineStarting];` you will have to make you method _public_.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you've created private method `-(BOOL) engineStarting` which means you can access it just within car class.
If you want that method to be visible in your main.m file move the declaration to car.h file it will make it public.

Comment: is there any way to access private method. If i do so then it will be public not private method

Comment: If you want to access a private method, it is not private anymore, but public. So put it in the class' (basic) interface. (There are ways to access private methods, but you do not want to do that.)

Comment: @shruthibr you can access private method using runtime but what's the point to create private method to access it later from external file?

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to keep `-engineStarting` privately, but use it outside the implementation? That's contradictory, because private means: "Unvisible outside the implementation."

Probably you are messed up with the terms. And you are right in a way: There is no black and white private/public pair, but a greyscale: Something can be visible to an implementation only (usually called private), to an implementation and subclass implementations (usually called protected), to an implementation and subclass implementations and friend classes (in a framework, usually called package) and public at all. Beside this you can have the desire to make a method public only to some subsystems (modules) and so on. So it is very complex.

What you can do for it, is to create a separate category and import the header of that category file to the area, where it should be visible.

```
//Car_PublicInFrameworkAddition.h
@interface Car(PublicInFrameworkAddition)
-(BOOL) engineStarting;
@end

//Car_PublicInFrameworkAddition.m
@implementation Car(PublicInFrameworkAddition)
-(BOOL) engineStarting
{
…
}
@end
```

Somewhere.m

```
// Somewhere should see the addition
#import "Car_PublicInFrameworkAddition.h"
```

Comment: how will you call it in main.m file (thats were the problem starts)

Comment: I added a sample (Somewhere.m) at the end of my answer.

Comment: i have done so please look at main.m file but still i am getting error

Comment: And you have added `-(BOOL) engineStarting;` to "Car+Maintanance.h"?